# Find a record by an array column when the input needs to be escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My Ethnicity model has an 'alternate_labels' column that is an array string.  It is defined in the schema as

```
t.string "alternate_labels", default: [], array: true
```

For example, one record is

```
{name: "Withhold", alternate_labels: ["Prefer Not to Say"]}
```

The one that I'm struggling with looks like this

```
{name: "White", alternate_labels: ["Caucasian", "White, (not of Hispanic / Latin origin)"]}
```

I'm trying to match a survey response to this record.  The line below works most of the time

```
Ethnicity.find_by("alternate_labels && ?", "{#{survey_response.race}}")
```

But it returns nil when survey.race is "White, (not of Hispanic / Latin origin)".  I suspect it's because the slash needs to be escaped, and possibly the parentheses.  Is there any way to rewrite the find_by query to work in these cases?  Or should I figure out how to pre-escape the survey_response.race before running the find_by query?  I think that means I would need to also escape the column value that I'm comparing to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure how this would be an escaping issue as that's handled by the placeholder.

Comment: Are you sure you typed this correctly because `"White / Caucasian, (not of Hispanic origin)"` will never match `"White, (not of Hispanic / Latin origin)"`

Comment: This is where having display labels and internal codes as two separate things really helps. This could be a code-word, not this huge text that, in time, may change slightly in ways that'll break your existing data. An internal code of, say, `w` can have as many labels as you want, they all map to the same thing.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for noticing the typo.  I've updated the question.

Comment: @tadman.  That makes sense.  But I think that would be really difficult to implement in my situation.  The client writes surveys in a third-party application (Qualtrics), and our app pulls the data from Qualtrics' API.  The method that I'm writing now converts that API data for our database.  So I think that I need the long block of text at some point.

Comment: You'll need to look at what you can change or normalize into various codes, and what needs to stay as-is for matching purposes. In many cases you'll have a mapping table from internal code to an equivalent used on other systems.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array. But I would really setup a separate table as array columns are a huge database modeling anti-pattern.

Comment: @max.  Yeah I'm definitely realizing why you say that.  So with your suggestion, I would add a table like EthnicityAlternateLabels and then have associations to it from the Ethnicity table?

Comment: I would go with a `ethnicity_labels` table (EthnicityLabel) which contains the normalized definitions and a `alternate_labels` table which is a join table betwen Ethnicity and EthnicityLabel. That also avoids some of the potential issues that @tadman mentioned.